# NullPointerException using iText 5.4.4

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using `iText` (in the latest version 5.4.4) for a generic print of user interfaces.

I have a Problem on some UIs, getting a NullPointerException:

```
23.10.2013 14:53:23.066  - ERROR -Container.doAdd()
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.setSimpleVars(ColumnText.java:312)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.setACopy(ColumnText.java:305)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.duplicate(ColumnText.java:294)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell.<init>(PdfPCell.java:255)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.<init>(PdfPRow.java:131)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.<init>(PdfPTable.java:261)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.setSimpleVars(ColumnText.java:347)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.setACopy(ColumnText.java:305)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.duplicate(ColumnText.java:294)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell.getMaxHeight(PdfPCell.java:968)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.calculateHeights(PdfPRow.java:209)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.getMaxHeights(PdfPRow.java:592)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(PdfPTable.java:990)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(PdfPTable.java:971)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1821)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.splitRow(PdfPRow.java:736)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1662)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(PdfDocument.java:2602)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:727)
    ... 24 more
```

After days of debugging my own code and the code of iText, I think I found the responsible line in class com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow line 699:

```
newCells[k].setColumn(null);
```

I removed this line in the iText-API and the NullPointer does not appear any more. Then the program generates a PDF again, but there still is a problem that there is to many vertical space, which i couldn't fix yet.

Does anybody have the same Problem? Is it a bug in iText?

Thanks for help!

MaKu

Comment: Can you run under debugger and check that at least some items of `newCells` equal to `null`?  If this is the case, then look at the code that initializes elements of this array.

Comment: I see that you work for an integrator for the financial sector. I also see that you've spent days on debugging your code. Two questions: (1) why didn't you contact iText support in order to prevent losing time? (2) we can't reproduce the problem without a SSCCE (see http://sscce.org ). Can you provide one? That specific line is important, so you shouldn't remove it. Note that neither `newCells` nor `newCells[k]` are `null`, the problem seems to be the fact that the `column` variable is set to `null`.